# docker phpmyadmin - how to add remote server

Tags: docker, server, phpmyadmin, remote-server

I can't seem to find the real installation path of my phpmyadmin.

I bash into the phpmyadmin container like this: (I'm on windows)

```
winpty docker exec -it pma_container_name sh
```

And then I got in by default in /var/www/html

and I see all the phpmyadmin files there.

I also noticed that there's also a phpmyadmin in **/etc/phpmyadmin** containing 3 config files, config.inc.php, congif.secret.inc.php, config.user.inc.php

There's also a phpmyadmin in the **/usr/src/phpmyadmin** containing all the phpmyadmin files.

Now, In /var/www/html - I just:

```
cp config.sample.inc.php config.inc.php
```

Then I created a sample file like:

```
touch phpinfo.php
```

and I access it in the browser on **localhost:8082/phpmyadmin.php**

and it totally works.

Now, since I know initially that it was reading my new file, added some config at the bottom:

```
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = ''; // remote ip address here
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

but still nothing happened in the phpmyadmin.

I can't seem to add or choose a remote server.

Any idea why?

I also noticed that the container is in Alpine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you run the container set the `PMA_HOST` environment variable with the host name of your MySQL server. You can also use `PMA_USER` and `PMA_PASSWORD`. For example:

```
docker run --name myadmin -d -e PMA_HOST=mydatabase.com -e PMA_USER=admin -e PMA_PASSWORD=password -p 8080:80 phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
```

If you want a custom configuration file, use:

```
-v /some/local/directory/config.user.inc.php:/etc/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php
```

For more information see the Docker image description:

https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/

Comment: Thanks mate, what do you mean by 'custom configuration file' - is it going to replace the current config.inc.php or it will just add a config. Thank you

Comment: It will replace it.

Comment: @kichik I have a similar issue on Mac with docker/laradock.  I am new to that environment. 1/ is it an issue to replace the current config.inc.php?  2/ I guess that the path above /some/local/directory is where the custom config file?  3/ apart the reference to remote servers what else should be in that file? 4/ should the -v ... command above be run everytime docker or the mac reboot?

Comment: @kichik -v command does not work in laradock